# Can I switch between all open windows?

Tags: gnome-shell, window-management

This is one feature I miss it on Win10, if I have 3 open chrome windows or file managers, can I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to switch between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Grave</kbd>.
*The <kbd>Grave</kbd> button is the button above <kbd>TAB</kbd> usually.

Comment: Thanks, but when I switch from other program, I need to press `Alt + Tab` and then `Alt + Grave` to choose the window I want?

Comment: Oh, I realized I can keep pressing `Alt` and switch to `Grave` from `Tab`. That's even better than Windows behavior!